# How to add Crypto++ library to Qt project

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crypto++

I downloaded the Crypto++ source and compiled the cryptlib project in Visual Studio 2013, and then I added the generated .lib file to my Qt project, which made my .pro file look like this:

```
QT       += core gui

QT += sql

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4):QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
        databasecontrol.h \
    test.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lcryptlib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lcryptlibd
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/ -lcryptlib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libcryptlib.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libcryptlibd.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/cryptlib.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/cryptlibd.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libcryptlib.a
```

Immediately after adding this library to the project, I build it and get the following error:

`:-1: error: No rule to make target 'C:/Users/Special Services/WorkOrder/libcryptlibd.a', needed by 'debug\untitled.exe'.  Stop.`

I believe I understand that the error is telling me that I need an additional line where all of the `else:win32` lines are under `DEPENDPATH`... or is it because the lines that were added use `$$PWD`, isn't that a Unix command? I've looked around at other instances of this error and I'm fairly certain the problem is with something in the .pro file here.

**EDIT:**

I decided to take a different approach. I got rid of anything that importing a library added to my .pro file, and instead just put this line of code in its place:

`win32:LIBS += C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\cryptopp\Win32\Output\Debug\cryptlib.lib` (The path to the cryptlib.lib file)

This built just fine. I made sure that all of the cryptopp header files were in my include directory, `C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\include\cryptopp`

I then tried to include a file, with `#include <cryptopp/aes.h>` and it built fine. The first time I built, there were 40+ warnings, but the second time I built, it built without any.

Comment: I made some progress and added an edit to the question describing the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libcryptlib.a
> else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/libcryptlibd.a
> ```

On Windows under Visual Studio, the name of the Crypto++ library is `cryptlib.lib`, not `libcryptlib.a`. *If* you used Cygwin (which I don't believe you did), then the name *would* be `libcryptopp.a`.

The `libcryptlibd.a` (notice the addition of the `d`) is probably not correct. It stands for 'debug', and its something that was used years ago in the Visual Studio 5.0/6.0 days. It was based on [Compiling and Integrating Crypto++ into the Microsoft Visual C++ Environment](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16388/Compiling-and-Integrating-Crypto-into-the-Microsof). *If* you renamed `Win32/Debug/cryptlib.lib` to `Win32/Debug/cryptlibd.lib`, then you are probably OK if your paths are OK.

I think the recommended way of doing things now is to use `cryptlib.lib` as the library (same name everywhere), and change the linker paths based on the configuration. The paths would be:

- Win32, Debug: `<crypto++ dir>/Win32/Debug/`
- Win64, Debug: `<crypto++ dir>/x64/Debug/`
- Win32, Release: `<crypto++ dir>/Win32/Release/`
- Win64, Release: `<crypto++ dir>/x64/Release/`

Here's a screen capture of adding `cryptlib.lib` under Visual Studio. Notice it applies to all configurations:

[image]

And here's how to change the linker paths so Visual Studio finds the proper `cryptlib.lib`:

[image]

In the above, `CRYPTOPP_LIB32` would be an environmental variable with a value like `C:\Users\Special Services\Crypto++\Win32\`. Similarly, `CRYPTOPP_LIB64` would be `C:\Users\Special Services\Crypto++\x64\`

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do these things under QtCreator.

Comment: I haven't got a chance to make an attempt to fix the problem yet, but I'm trying to understand the error - is it because i've included a release version of cryptlib.lib instead of the debug version, and Qt was expecting the debug version? So then I have to change the IDE options so that it expects a release version instead of a debug version?