# Crypto++ build with msvc /MDd cryptlib.lib Can't find cryptopp.lib when linking

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crypto++

I built the last available version of the library (5.6.5) wanting to use it in a Qt msvc project. The issue is, that the linker want's for some reason the cryptopp.lib that is produced when building the fips dll.

This is my config (only the relevant):

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/thirdparty/Win/cryptopp/include
LIBS += -L$$PWD/thirdparty/Win/cryptopp/debug/ -lcryptlib
```

The compiler output:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cryptopp.lib'
```

EDIT: 
The link command + the result: Which the result is the same as above.

`link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /NODEFAULTLIB:MSVCRT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\QtTrafficBrowser.exe @C:\Users\Mij\AppData\Local\Temp\QtTrafficBrowser.exe.1316.6203.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cryptopp.lib'
jom: C:\Users\Mij\qt_creator\qtTrafficBrowser\build-QtTrafficBrowser-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\QtTrafficBrowser.exe] Error 1104
jom: C:\Users\Mij\qt_creator\qtTrafficBrowser\build-QtTrafficBrowser-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_32bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2`

I am not trying to use the DLL!! I know it's different and I knew it from the start so stop asking me not to use it. The problem is that when linking with cryptlib.lib the linker asks for cryptopp.lib also. Is it clear?

Comment: change `-lcryptlib` to `-lcryptopp`

Comment: cryptopp is not the library I have/want to use, cryptopp is the dll loader for the fips dll if I declare both I get a redefinition error, which is logical.

Comment: @silajim: Why are you building it yourself? Because, in the **FIPS 140-2 Validation** section on the homepage it reads and I quote **(You cannot compile Crypto++ yourself and claim FIPS 140-2 conformance on the resulting module, unless the it goes through the validation process again.)**

Link: https://www.cryptopp.com/#fips

You have to use the binaries providing by them which are already FIPS compliant. Otherwise, you have to get it validate yourself.

And, in the binaries, you'll find the `cryptopp.lib` and `cryptopp.dll` in debug and release directories . That means `-lcryptopp`.

Comment: I don't want the fips library, I want to use the full library in a Qt project. But the full library compiled using MDd (instead of MTd which is the default) for some reason in the linking demands the cryptopp.lib. I compile using msvc2015.

Comment: You should show the output of a compile command, and you should show the output of the link command. Providing just the error is not very useful. The DLL is not a regular DLL; and you should not use it unless you have a specific need. Using it is painful as detailed on the Crypto++ wiki. Also see [FIPS DLL](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/FIPS_DLL) and [Visual Studio](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Crypto++ library to Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223528/how-to-add-crypto-library-to-qt-project)

Comment: Your link command does not specify `"cryptopp.lib"` as an additional library. I'm guessing either (1) a third party library you have not discussed is bringing it in; or (2) your code has a `#pragma (lib, "cryptopp");`. Can you enumerate the other libraries you are using? Can you verify your project is not using a pragma? Crypto++ has the pragma in `dll.h`, but its only activated when `_DLL` and `CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS` are defined, and that should only happen with the FIPS DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dumb.
I added the dll.h into my project, that's why it was asking for the cryptopp.lib. 
Removed it, and boom, works.

People having a similar issue, look at this also. [LNK1104 Cryptopp.lib with CRYPTOPP_DEFAULT_NO_DLL defined in dll project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846409/lnk1104-cryptopp-lib-with-cryptopp-default-no-dll-defined-in-dll-project)

Comment: I just want to thank you for posting this! I had the same problem and same cause.